# Tail recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion

I was trying to write recursion function,to find factorial of a number.

```
    int factorial(int input,int *answer)
    {
       if ( input ==0 )        
       {                       
        return 0;
       }

       *answer  = *answer * input;
       factorial(input -1, answer);
    }
```

What will you say about this function? Is it tail recursive?

Comment: Without a return statement, this function yields nothing but undefined behavior.

Comment: @James: Actually, it looks like he's trying to store the result into `answer` instead of returning any value. And it seems to assume that `*answer` is initialized to 1.

Comment: @casablanca:  That's fine, but the function has a return type of `int` and does not actually return a value.

Comment: @James: Agreed, a return type at all makes no sense here. `void` would have worked just fine.

Comment: yes, true void is not required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing tail recursive functions (especially tail recursive functions) it is often helpful to have a helper function in addition to another function which has a more friendly interface.  The friendly interface function really just sets up the less friendly function's arguments.

```
static unsigned factorial_helper(unsigned input, unsigned acc) {
       if (intput == 0) {
           return acc;
       }
       return factorial_helper(input-1, acc * input);
}

unsigned factorial(int input) {
    if (input < 0) {
        do_something_bad();
    }
    return factorial_helper(input, 1);
}
```

By passing an accumulator value you avoid having to use pointers or do any computations upon  returning from called functions, which makes the functions truely tail recursive.

Comment: On line 2, you wrote `intput` instead of `input`. Doesn't compile like that.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a link with a definition: http://phoenix.goucher.edu/~kelliher/cs23/feb21.html

> "A function is tail recursive if the very last thing it does is make its recursive call."

In the code you posted, the last thing the function does is make a recursive call to itself, so by this definition, it is tail-recursive.