# Tail recursion in C and SICP

Tags: c

I'm confused by the following paragraph in  SICP:

> One reason that the distinction between process and procedure may be confusing is that most implementations of common languages (including Ada, Pascal, and C) are designed in such a way that the interpretation of **any recursive procedure** consumes an amount of memory that grows with the number of procedure calls, even when the process described is, in principle, iterative. As a consequence, these languages can describe iterative processes only by resorting to special-purpose ``looping constructs'' such as do, repeat, until, for, and while.

As I understand it, you can actually write tail recursive procedures(functions) in C:

[Tail recursion in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935501/tail-recursion-in-c#3935573)

So, what is the correct interpretation of the mentioned paragraph?

Comment: While writing functions in the style suggested by the linked answer helps with tail recursion, actual compiler support is also needed, that the compiler can detect tail recursion and then reuse the function context. If the compiler can't do that then all you have is normal recursion, only that the recursive call is made in a special place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, while you can *write* tail-recursive algorithms in C, there is no guarantee that the generated code will not allocate additional stack memory at each tail call. This is exactly what used to happen in virtually all historic C implementations, making tail recursion impractical.

In modern C this is a quality of implementation issue. For example, GCC has been able to optimize many instances of tail recursion into equivalent iteration for many years now. Still, the key difference in comparison to Scheme is that Scheme *guarantees* tail call elimination, while C doesn't and is unlikely to ever do so.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that GCC did that optimization. Perhaps SICP was written before that, though it is still an important point that the optimization isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @JohnColeman Not only does GCC optimize that, it optimizes even some *non-tail* recursions, such as the traditional recursive factorial. It's [quite fascinating](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22PTAEBUE8AcFNUgewK4CdQGNEBN4AtZVYAaURdAG0QENtRqA7UWAD2oFtoLYA6AKACWDAC6gAZtQzCAFENENk7AJSgA3n1CgBY0NIXtQAXkOgADEo2bQRYWiYBGANyWbd0PtAAqcZJkeAtKD2Ss4AvnxAAAA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g530%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O2%22%7D%5D%7D), really.